# How to find and list all UWP apps / packages?

Tags: c#, winapi, uwp, windows-10

My goal is to find and launch a UWP app by name (e.g. Twitter). I'm currently using an elevated desktop extension, following a guide by Stefan Wick.

In my full-trust Win32 console process, I'm currently using the PackageManager to find and list all the UWP apps, and it works on my machine. However, when I send my finalized app package to another user, nothing appears on his screen, even after running elevated.

Here's my current code:

```
var PkgMgr = new PackageManager();

var currUserPkgs = PkgMgr.FindPackagesForUser(string.Empty);

foreach (Package pkg in currUserPkgs)
{
        string pkgName = pkg.DisplayName;
        if (pkgName == "")
        {
                continue;
        }

        if (pkgName.Contains(appName) || appName.Contains(pkgName) ||
        percentSimilarity(appName, pkgName) >= 0.50)
        {
                // we found it

                appPkgName = pkg.Id.FamilyName;
                break;
        }
}
```

Why does this not bring up any packages on another user's machine? There's no error message that's called.

Also, is there another solution that can locate all UWP packages? Thank you!

Comment: What does `PkgMgr.FindPackagesForUser(string.Empty)` return?

Comment: @mm8 it actually retrieves all the packages on my machine, but when I push it to another user, it does not retrieve anything for them. That too even as an elevated process.